# Direct import from Oracle to Hadoop using Sqoop

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I want to use --direct parameter when I import the data from the Oracle. Is it possible to use data dump/pump utility using --direct option? Do I need to install any Oracle utility on my shell? If yes, please suggest what do I need to install?

Dharmesh

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there's no Sqoop connector that uses the DataPump utility.

Oracle does have their own (closed source) big data connectors. I believe SQL Loader for Hadoop uses datapump format.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle Big Data Connector (Loader) is used to import data from Hadoop to Oracle.  But, not from Oracle to Hadoop.